# What is the highest resolution of infrared photography of Earth available from satellites?

Tags: earth, photography

What is the best resolution of infrared photo taken from space of earth?
Is it possible to see on this picture, for example, animals or humans (temperature of body is different than ground)?

Is it possible to download or buy such photos for any areas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_imagery

Comment: Related: http://space.stackexchange.com/q/19537/58

Comment: *I'm afraid that information is classified.* - You'll likely get an answer on the highest resolution of *civilian* infrared photography of Earth...

Comment: I'd say KH-11 infrared imagery (at around 50cm-1m GSD in thermal IR if I had to guess), but we will never know....

Comment: Only the National Reconnaissance Office can answer this, and they won't.